# How to fix the auto code formatting in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

When I save a method and get back to it later, all of my variable names become temp and all of my parameters becomes arg and the code indentation get changed.
Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour that you are experiencing is not code formatting at all. You immage is experiencing an issue where it can't access original source code. Thus it uses a backup solution and decomples method bytecode. During the compilation process the variable names are erased, so they can't be re-created during the decompilation, and generic substitudes are used instead.

Now, why you are missing sources is another question. First of all it's important to check if you get some exceptions. Often these happen when you open or save your image, but also thaty may occur when you save methods.

Depending on the Pharo version you may be missing .changes or .sources files. This often happens when you more an image without moving other supporting files.

Comment: That is true, what happened before is that after launching my image I realize that my code was not saved from my last 5 sessions. That is like 6 hours of coding, so I learned online that I can recover that from the Image.changes file. I dragged the file into my image and I was able to browse my changes, after that I started to "file in" a change after the other because the changes are saved in as chuncks each method separately. When I finished this started to happened. I could not save the image, I had to save it as a new image. I hope that gives you a hint of how I can fix that.